# Error in installing face recognition module in python

Tags: python, face-recognition

I want to use the face recognition module of python in a project but when I am trying to install it using the command "pip install face_recognition" or "pip install face-recognition", it is showing an error and is not installing. This is the screenshot of the error:[image]

How to fix this error and install the module?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not forget to install cmake firt,t then VS's c++ Cmake pack

Answer (score 0):

You should install a C++ compiler. I would suggest Visual Studio C++.
This is because the face_recognition package does not have prebuilt wheels for your platform and therefore you need to build them yourself when you install.
Anyhow just installing C++ build tolls will be sufficient.
Verify your installation

```
cl
```

And then re-run

```
pip install face_recognition
```

Comment: I had installed Microsoft Visual C++ and then I tried to run "pip install face_recognition". But then also it was showing the same error.

Comment: Try verifying that the install succeeded. Sometimes a reboot is necessary. Also check that if python is 64 bit also the C++ compiler should be 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Face-recognition python module uses C++, so your computer needs somehow to compile the library it is using. Install any of the **C++ compilers** (for example minGW) & be sure is that compiler executable is added to your global PATH. After that try to install face-recognition library.

If the step above does not work - try using python **32-bit build** (once I have encountered this error because my python build was 64-bit). It may help in some of the cases.

Use p**ython version == 3.7** (any other versions does not compatible with face-recognition module)

Install dlib dependency and try to use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) for installing & manipulating environments.

**P.S.** you need to install C++ compiler, not Visual Studio itself. Visual studio is an IDE, while compiler is not.

Comment: I'm working almost a year with face_recognition / dlib and Python 3.8 / 3.9 and got no problems of "incompatability".

Comment: I had already installed MinGW in my system and also it is added in the environment variables. Still when I tried to install face-recognition, it was showing the same error. Then I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 also, still it didn't work. I tried to fix the error by installing cmake but still the error was not resolved. How can I solve this error? Also if you want to know my python version, it is Python 3.9.6